# Castle Windsor resolve types of service implementations without creating instances

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

In Castle Windsor IoC, if you want to find the types that register a service, you can do it the following way:

```
List<Type> typeList = new List<Type>();

foreach (var item in moduleContainer.ResolveAll<IMyService>())
{
     var theType = typeof(item);
     Console.WriteLine("Found implementation: " + item.Name);
     typeList.insert(theType);
}
```

However, this method actually **creates an instance** of the type.

**How do I resolve implementation `Type`(s) of a service interface without creating an instance?**

Comment: I suppose you could `moduleContainer.Release(item)` immediately after adding it to the list. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var handlers = container.Kernel.GetHandlers(typeof(IMyService));
```

Comment: Sorry to revisit this but it **does not return a `Type`** object which is what I need here. Is there a way to get a `Type` from a IHandler?

Comment: `handler.ComponentModel.Implementation`